# How to remove/hide "Likee Videos" from imo main menu?

Tags: imo-instant-messenger

As shown in the picture below, Likee Videos appears between stories and recent chats? How can we get rid of Likee videos, so that it doesn't not appear there?

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Go to settings 
Then you can see " Function"
Click it turn off likee vedio

Comment: I went to setting and i have not seen "Function"